# Using Karate as Library to my Java @Tests

Tags: karate

The best way using karate is with Karate DSL in feature files. However I just wants to check if I can utilize karate as a library to my java based framework.

For example I know I can use below code and automate Chrome using Chrome DevTools.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Chrome chrome = Chrome.startHeadless();
        chrome.setLocation("https://github.com/login");
        ......
        chrome.quit();
    } 
}
```

Can I do similar for com.intuit.karate.driver.WebDriver for automating any WebDriver based Browsers (like ChromeWebDriver, GeckoWebDriver etc.) without having feature files?

Can I use similar way to automate API tests with my own @Test methods but using karate library underneath in test method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion with Peter Thomas (The Karate Creator) I figured out a way to do it.
 Here is sample code to launch Chrome webdriver Browser via karate.

```
HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
map.put("type","chromedriver");
map.put("executable","/Users/vxt82/Apps/chromedriver");
HashMap httpConfig = new HashMap<String,Object>();
httpConfig.put("readTimeout", 120000);
map.put("httpConfig",httpConfig);
ChromeWebDriver driver = new ChromeWebDriver(new DriverOptions(null, map, null, 9515, "chromedriver"));
```

And then you can call methods like

```
driver.setUrl("https://github.com/login");
driver.input("#login_field", "dummy");
driver.input("#password", "world");
driver.submit().click("input[name=commit]");
```

P.S. : As said by Thomas this is not recommended way of using Karate but posting answer just in case anyone is trying to use karate for test automation as a dependency and write test in java instead of using feature file.

Comment: thanks. for people attempting to write a test-framework from scratch, here is my very sincere advice: `please don't`. see this video: https://twitter.com/ptrthomas/status/1247752487093690369

Comment: an update - please note that Karate has a Java API in 1.0 onwards: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1353969718730788865

Answer (score 0):

EDIT in 2021 - Karate 1.0 will have a Java API for all the core capabilities, see: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1353969718730788865

---

Not recommended because you would lose things like reports and the ability to do [debugging](https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1167533484560142336).

[Here is an example](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/driver/demo/Demo01JavaRunner.java) for browser automation.

```
    Chrome driver = Chrome.start();        
    driver.setUrl("https://github.com/login");
    driver.input("#login_field", "dummy");
    driver.input("#password", "world");
    driver.submit().click("input[name=commit]");
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. I think I need to rephrase my question for clarity. I know we can do with Chrome (DevTools driver) but can we do similarly with ChromwWebDriver / GecokWebDriver ? I see the start is required to have scenario context as mandatory parameter.

Comment: I am not much concerned about the reports or other features comes with it, I am mainly interested in using Karate webdriver java client only. so it it possible?  I would also like to see if we can using karate api testing with java syntax instead of DSL (in feature file)

Comment: @VikasThange yes, your starting point has to be a `ScenarioContext` - you have to figure out how to construct it from the code, I don't have the time to explain it to you :)

Comment: I got this working by passing some mandatory options and null as ScenarioContext. Posting here as answer so it can help somebody who try to so similar stuff. Thanks Thomas!