# Does Karate UI supports multi remote/web base chat application?

Tags: karate

Does Karate UI supports multi remote or any web based Chat application? Is it possible to initiate two drivers? Can someone suggest here?

```
Background:
  * configure driver1 = { type: 'chrome' }
  * configure driver2 = { type: 'chrome' }

Scenario: try to login to github
    and then do a google search
  
  Given driver1 "<chat-url>"
  And input("#user1", 'Hello User')
  
  Given driver2 '<chat -url>'
  And match html("#user2) contains "Hello User"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karate needs changes to support 2 browsers in the same scenario at the same time. I suggest you try the Java API here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/driver/demo/Demo01JavaRunner.java

This is not a priority for us right now. you can try find others who need this or contribute code changes if needed. you will need to watch out for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61331058/143475

Comment: Okay thank you, let me try suggested links and revert here with my findings.